# Как передать файл в контроллер через ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

В представлении есть много полей с данными, также есть прикрепленное количество файлов. Все данные собираю в объект и передаю в формате JSON в контроллер. Проблема с состоит с передачей файлов(это несколько input type=file, в каждом по одному файлу). Все данные потом на сервере обрабатываются и сохраняются в базе. При передаче формой - все хорошо передается, но при такой передаче надо обновлять страницу. Поэтому решил делать через Ajax.

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Файлы через ajax можно пропихнуть используя `FormData`

Comment: Как? У меня получается объект JSON из всех полей, я его в контроллере распаковываю в обычный объект. Мне надо для файлов вводить отдельный параметр List<IFormFile>?Тут есть вопрос как он будет распознаваться в контроллере, как его подготовить в js?

Comment: Просто запихивайте файлы в `formdata` через `append()` и кидайте собранную `formdata` ajax'ом, на стороне контроллера разгребайте `Request.Files`

Comment: то есть параметры в методе использовать не надо?

Comment: должен и без параметров всё схавать

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Попробую, через полчасика отпишу.

Comment: Что все идет не так. С данными передаю $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/BugReport/Edit",
        data: { JSONData: JSONData},
        cache: false,
        async: true
    }); Если добавить FormData - запрос не отправляется. В контроллере тоже нет Request.Files, есть Request.Form.Files, но у меня он пустой

Comment: Так закиньте просто `data:formdata`, зачем json варганить

Comment: а там будут все поля с формы? или их надо добавлять как и файлы? У меня не по сабмиту запрос происходит. От сабмита и модели отказался так как там система ждет ответа, а он мне не нужен.

Comment: нет, там куча полей, все передаются хорошо, проблема лишь передать еще список файлов

Comment: Попробуйте их также приаппендить к `formdata`

Comment: jquery.js:8463 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation. Попробовал добавить под свободное значение всю строку

Comment: Заработало вроде, даже связывается с параметром в методе. Сейчас доделаю - скину что к чему.

Comment: В общем, если интересно. Использовал не Ajax jquery, а XMLHttpRequest() ----------------------formData.append('JSONData', JSONData);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/BugReport/Edit', true);
        request.send(formData);                             ----Фалы добавлялись выше, в конце добавил JSON со всеми остальными параметрами. В методе контроллера JSON строка автоматом подходит под входной параметр, потом я уже её перевожу в объект. Фалы лежат по адресу Request.Form.Files... Все скачивается в массив байтов хорошо. Спасибо за подсказки.